# How to play an audio file repeatedly without a memory leak?

Tags: c#, naudio

I am using NAudio to play a wav file

```
    WaveOut waveOut;
    WaveFileReader reader;
    bool laeuft = false;
    private void abspielen()
    {
        if (!laeuft)
        {
            reader = new WaveFileReader("test.wav");
            waveOut = new WaveOut();
            laeuft = true;
        }
        waveOut.Init(reader);
        waveOut.Play();
    }
```

It plays only once and stays mute. Before that I used

```
    private void abspielenAsync(string was)
    {
        using (var reader = new WaveFileReader(was))
        {
            using (var waveOut = new WaveOut())
            {
                waveOut.Init(reader);
                waveOut.Play();
            }
        }
    }
```

Which worked repeatedly, but somewhere in this is a memory leak. Where is it? How to play repeatedly without a memory leak?

Comment: what if `waveOut.Init()` ia called once too ? (inside `if` clause)

Comment: @Tigran Then it plays once only. In fact, without reader and waveOut each time, it does not repeat. But even calling dispose on waveout and reader makes it grow. Commenting the whole audio playing method shows constant memory usage.

Comment: "somewhere in this is a memory leak". Please define "memory leak" and how you've measured it. If your investigation is only as deep as Task Manager, you're going to have to do more work (with a memory profiler) to get to the bottom of this.

Comment: Where to look in the diagnostic tools?

Comment: The diagnostic tools is available in Visual Studio, or you can use 3rd party profiler like Deleaker. I beleive NAudio is pure .net library so most likely you need a .net profiler. But there is a chance that the leak comes from unmanaged code, because WaveOut anyway has to call some system code to play audio.